# Geometric interpretations of several algebraic concepts

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I would like to have some geometric intuition for
- Noetherian rings/modules
- Local rings
- Projective modules
- Injective modules

As an illustration of what I am looking for, I was told once that  that for a local ring to be a domain roughly means that locally a curve has only one component.

Thanks

Comment: I think this question is too vague. Suppose X is an algebraic variety - by which I mean "something glued from finitely many affine algebraic sets". To it you can associate a sheaf of rings (the structure sheaf). These rings are naturally Noetherian and reduced. If X is connected, it is irreducible iff all its affine sections are integral domains. At any point, you can construct the "local ring of the point". This is a noetherian local ring; its minimal prime ideals are in bijection with the irreducible components of X passing through it. In particular, it is a domain iff there is only one ...

Comment: ... component passing through it. In this sense, geometry gives you intuition for Noetherian rings. Algebraic vector bundles on varieties correspond to locally free coherent sheaves - over affine varieties, these are locally free Noetherian modules.